# Behat/Mink and Select2 combo

Tags: php, jquery-select2, behat, mink

I try to create a Behat scenario with web UI using Select2.

When I try to change the select value, I've an Behat error because of the base select which is hide by Select2.

But I already have an error with the select2 component because mink can not interact with it.

Have you already use Behat/Mink with Select2 ? Have you tips to help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally write a Behat to interact with Select2 field like a user can do.

Here an extract of the most complete step :

```
/**
 * @When /^(?:|I )fill in select2 input "(?P<field>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" with "(?P<value>(?:[^"]|\\")*)" and select "(?P<entry>(?:[^"]|\\")*)"$/
 */
public function iFillInSelectInputWithAndSelect($field, $value, $entry)
{
    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

    $inputField = $page->find('css', $field);
    if (!$inputField) {
        throw new \Exception('No field found');
    }

    $choice = $inputField->getParent()->find('css', '.select2-selection');
    if (!$choice) {
        throw new \Exception('No select2 choice found');
    }
    $choice->press();

    $select2Input = $page->find('css', '.select2-search__field');
    if (!$select2Input) {
        throw new \Exception('No input found');
    }
    $select2Input->setValue($value);

    $this->getSession()->wait(1000);

    $chosenResults = $page->findAll('css', '.select2-results li');
    foreach ($chosenResults as $result) {
        if ($result->getText() == $entry) {
            $result->click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm going to Open Source Select2 contexts in a few days on Github.

Comment: I open sourced the select2 context on [Github](https://github.com/novaway/BehatCommonContext). The branch 1.x is compatible with Behat2 and 2.x is compatible with Behat3.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with that one but I've went through it with the info I found at [Filling in hidden inputs with Behat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7561114/filling-in-hidden-inputs-with-behat).

My solution is only slightly different:

```
/** 
 * @Given /^I fill hidden field "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ 
*/
public function iFillHiddenFieldWith($class, $value){
  $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', $class)->setValue($value);
}
```

And then I use it in the following way:

```
And I fill hidden field "#s2id_edit-my-field input" with "random value".
```